# How to send two images from server to client with socket programming (TCP)?

Tags: c#, socket.io

I want to send some images from server to client. I want when user connect to server and request for images, i sent some images to that. I searched but all of answers about send one image from client to server not server to client! 
I wrote below code for send one image from server to client, but i get below error in runtime, because i shutdown socket and then called 'SendCallback' method. Where i shutdown and close socket?

```
  public class ImageSocketServer
{
    public class StateObject
    {
        // Client socket.
        public Socket WorkSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.
        public const int BufferSize = 256;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        // Received data string.
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public ManualResetEvent AllDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private Socket handler;

    public void StartListening(string ip, int port)
    {
        IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        listener.Bind(serverEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(port);

        while (true)
        {
            AllDone.Reset();

            listener.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, listener);

            AllDone.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        AllDone.Set();
        Socket listener = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(asyncResult);
        StateObject state = new StateObject { WorkSocket = handler };
        handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            ReadCallback, state);


    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        string content = string.Empty;

        StateObject state = (StateObject)asyncResult.AsyncState;
         handler = state.WorkSocket;

        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(asyncResult);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf(Cache.EndOfMessage, StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1)
            {
                //Send(handler, @"C:\Users\f.hashemian\Pictures\Camera Roll\test.jpg");
                SendImage(handler, @"C:\Users\f.hashemian\Pictures\Camera Roll\test.jpg");

                //

            }
            else
            {
                handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, ReadCallback, state);
            }
        }
    }

    private  void SendImage(Socket client, string imagePath)
    {
        byte[] imgBuff = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
        var length = imgBuff.Length;

        Send(client, BitConverter.GetBytes(length));
        sendDone.WaitOne();
        Send(client, imgBuff);
        sendDone.WaitOne();


        //Here close connection and i have error in SendCallback
        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();

    }

    private  void Send(Socket client, byte[] byteData)
    {
        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket handler = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            int byteSent = handler.EndSend(asyncResult);

            sendDone.Set();


            //

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```

This is about send one image with send size of image and then send image to client. If you have any tutorial about some images, please send link here

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent.set?view=netframework-1.1#System_Threading_ManualResetEvent_Set, you should call Reset() method after calling WaitOne() on ManualResetEvent to set it in nonsignaled state.

```
private  void SendImage(Socket client, string imagePath)
{
    byte[] imgBuff = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
    var length = imgBuff.Length;

    Send(client, BitConverter.GetBytes(length));
    sendDone.WaitOne();
    sendDone.Reset();
    Send(client, imgBuff);
    sendDone.WaitOne();
    sendDone.Reset();


    //Here close connection and i have error in SendCallback
    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    handler.Close();

}
```

Otherwise, the second WaitOne() will be skipped (since the event is in signaled state) and the Shutdown() method will be called. As a result, you will receive an exception in SendCallback, because the connection is already closed. In your case, it is better to use AutoResetEvent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=netframework-4.8 which resets automatically after releasing a single waiting thread.